# CSS delay when Laravel mail function is used

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 6. I have a button which gets triggered when it has been clicked. The click event does two things. It adds a css class to the button which shows an animated svg spinner to indicate that something is loading and it sends information to my controller which sends an e-mail.
The spinner class is set as soon as the button is clicked, but the problem is that the spinner is only shown when the mail has been sent. But I want the spinner to be shown while the gets sent so the user knows that he has to wait.

This is my .spinner class

```
.spinner {
background-image: url(storage/app/public/img/spinner.svg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
}
```

This is the button from my child component which can be clicked:

```
<button class="btn btn-success teamplayerButton" @click="addSpinner($event.target); $emit('del-match', match.id);">Add
</button>
```

The addSpinner method on the child component:

```
addSpinner(match) {
match.classList.toggle('spinner');
match.innerText = "";
}
```

The parent component gets the emitted match.id and makes a get request to a route which sends a mail like this:

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new ReceivedInvitation(Auth::user()->name, $receiverName));
```

Here is a short video to show you what I mean.
[click here](https://youtu.be/H_4-b596GJM)

Why does the css depends on what php(laravel) on the backend does?
The css gets set instant but the animation is shown after a few seconds.
When I remove the call of the mail function in my controller, and try it again, the spinner is shown instantly.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the CSS changes instantly, but the actual image isn't  being loaded until after the AJAX call finishes.

I would check your network tab to understand how the spinner file is being loaded, and see if its being blocked for some reason by the AJAX call. If it isn't just a static file, something else might be going on.

Comment: I checked the network tab and noticed, that the image is on status "pending" for a few seconds before it changes to status "200" when it's shown. It's just a static file. What can I do to make it independent from the ajax call?
You can see the network tab [here](https://imgur.com/GgdsuR9)

Comment: You can always just embed the SVG directly instead of loading a static file. Without getting to far into the intricies of the framework you're using I'd say that's an easy fix.